# Чтение строк из файла

Tags: c++

Нужно написать программу, позволяющую считать из файла строки со смешанными данными. Файл:

> Ivanov 20 3
>   Petrov 18 2
>   Sidorov 24 4

Каким образом забить такие данные в массив, чтобы потом можно было отсортировать?

Comment: Язык, система, средство разработки?

Comment: visual c++

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Считывание строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376460/23044)

Answer (score 4):

`std::istream` умеет читать данные, разделенные пробельными символами.
Можно объявить структуру для записей в файле

```
struct Record {
    std::string name;
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

и прочитать файл в `std::vector` этих структур

```
std::vector<Record> records;

std::ifstream file("file.txt");
Record tmp;
while (file >> tmp.name >> tmp.a >> tmp.b) // Читаем поля если файл не закончился.
    records.push_back(tmp);
```

После чтения можно проверить был ли файл прочитан полностью

```
if (file.bad()) {
    std::cout << "I/O error\n";  // Пока файл читали, с ним что-то случилось.
    return 1;
}
if (!file.eof()) {
    std::cout << "Invalid data\n";  // Не удалось распарсить число.
    return 1;
}
```

И наконец отсортировать этот вектор:

```
auto by_name = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.name < b.name; };
std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), by_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```

В качестве массива используй Vector. Точно не помню, вроде его и сортировать можно сразу.

Comment: Можно применить контейнер set. Там элементы сразу при добавлении сортируются.