# Считывание строки

Tags: строки, c++

На вход подается описание бинарного дерева. На листьях (висячих вершинах) этого дерева написаны целые числа (от -10^6 до 10^6). Идем от корня дерева, случайно поварачивая направо или налево (с вероятностями 0.5).

Чему равно cреднее значение числа на листе, в который мы в конечном счете придем? Ответ вывести с точностью до двух знаков после запятой.

Данную задачу можно решить без дерева. Когда встречаешь "(" - уменьшать вероятность, когда ")" - увеличивать: `res=a[i]*(0.5)^(b[i])`, где `a[i]` — это какое-то число из строки ввода, `b[i]` — скобочный итог к моменту, когда мы встретили это число. И суммировать результаты. 
Т.е. когда скобка, он должен прибавлять или вычитать к s. А когда число - выполнять действия с ним. Подскажите.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str,st;

int index = 0,k=0,i=0;
double s=0,res=0;
res = 0;
char chr;
getline(cin,str);

while (index < str.length())
{
    chr = str[index];

    if ((chr!='(')||(chr!=')'||(chr!=' ')))
        {
            st = chr;
            k = atoi(st.c_str()); cout << "k=" << k << endl;
            res = res + k*pow(0.5, s); cout << "s=" << s << endl;
        }

    if (chr == '(')
    {
        s = s+1 ;

    }
    if (chr == ')')
    {
        s = s-1;

    }
    cout << "ravn" << res<<endl;

    index++;
}
    cout << "ravn" << res;
        system("pause");
}
```

На вход подавться будет вот такое: (1 3(2 4))

Comment: Так, как сделал я, тоже нельзя. Нужно все же целое число. Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: @doomsday: `(1 3(2 4))` строка не является числом (как его обычно записывают). Какой ответ ожидается для `(1 3(2 4))` строки? Все ли числа состоят только из одной цифры? Что необходимо сделать с этими числами после преобразования в int?

Comment: Не нужно совсем вопрос менять (существующие ответы становятся бессмысленными). Решение задачи по обходу дерева и распознавание числа в строке являются несколько разными задачами. ;) В чём неясность состоит? @iksuy уже показал [как можно цифру `char` в `int` превратить](http://hashcode.ru/questions/376460#376622). Мой ответ содержит, как строку в число превратить. Я уже привёл [ссылку на пример кода, как отдельные цифры в число собрать](https://gist.github.com/zed/f199d5a0c453be2e9681#file-csum_block-c). Я не вижу, что эти подсказки использованы в коде в вопросе.

Comment: @jfs, у меня несколько чисел, при чем я не знаю, сколько. И каждое число нужно считать отдельно, да и еще и так, чтобы мы знали, сколько раз встречается скобки до этого. Я не понимаю, как сделать это.

Comment: @jfs, т.е. алгоритм следующий: подается формата (22 23(1 4)), программа должна считать количество скобок, встречающихся перед числом, определять число и считать для каждого числа `res=a[i]*(0.5)^(b[i])`, где `a[i]` — это какое-то число из строки ввода, `b[i]` — скобочный итог к моменту, и суммировать такие результаты.

Comment: *"у меня несколько чисел, при чем я не знаю, сколько."* -- __все__ примеры в моём предыдущем комментарии __уже__ поддерживают работу с несколькими числами с неизвестным общем количеством (до конца файла, блока чтение идёт). Если это не является __совершенно__ очевидным, то я бы сперва потренировался на более простых задачах, например, *посчитать сумму целых чисел (положительных и отрицательных) из файла, где числа разделены запятыми и (опционально) пробелами (`" \t\r\n\f\v"`)* -- если не __предельно__ ясно как такую задачу решить, то лучше новый вопрос задать.

Comment: @jfs,посмотрите, пожалуйста, я там поправил, но выдается ошибка 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/377262/c-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы преобразовать число в строке `str` в тип `int`: [`int i = stoi(str);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

#### [Пример](http://ideone.com/6HjIsW)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) {
      int i = stoi(line);
      cout << i << endl;
   }
}
```

#### Ввод

```
1
-1
             2
             3 rest
- 4
```

#### Вывод

```
1
-1
2
3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi
```

Вывод показывает, что `stoi()` игнорирует пробелы до числа, игнорирует произвольные символы после числа в строке и не разрешает пробелы между минусом и целой частью числа.

Comment: строка в таком случае должна обязательно начинаться с числа. А у меня возможно любое начало. 
Даже я из строки буду каждый символ в цикле переводить в char, можно ли проверить число в нем или нет???

Comment: @doomsday, можно использовать функцию [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) из заголовка <cctype>(или <locale>)

Comment: @Alex Krass, тут тоже необходимо, чтобы начиналось с числа. Я написал код( добавил его в вопрос), только не пойму почему он каждый раз распечатывает s и k? Ведь он не должен заходить туда(например, (()))..

Comment: @doomsday: не верно. Строка может начинаться с пробелов, [`stoi()` пропускает пробелы и игнорирует символы после числа](http://ideone.com/6HjIsW)

Comment: @jfs, только он падает при скобках.. И как реализовать мою программу, мне так и не подскази собственно.

Comment: @doomsday: *"только он падает при скобках"* -- наверху я оставил комментарий с вопросами по постановке задачи. Отредактируй вопрос, включив ответы на мои вопросы. Скобки не являются традиционно частью чисел, поэтому `(1 3(2 4))` я не могу угадать какой ответ желателен.

Comment: @Alex Krass: благодаря Microsoft, результат [`isdigit()` может зависеть от текущей локали](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19440958), поэтому лучше явное сравнение [`if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')` использовать](https://gist.github.com/zed/f199d5a0c453be2e9681#file-csum_block-c), которое гарантировано С стандартом (в любой кодировке, цифры подряд идут).

Comment: @jfs, я поправил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @jfs: Ладно уж вам ругать Microsoft. [Стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) гласит:

(7.4/2) Character handling `<ctype.h>`

> The behavior of these functions is affected by the current locale.

(7.4.1.5/2) The `isdigit` function

> The `isdigit` function tests for any decimal-digit character (as defined in 5.2.1).

(5.2.1.2/1 Multibyte characters)

> The execution character set may also contain multibyte
characters [...] The presence, meaning, and representation of any additional members is locale-specific.

То есть, разрешено стандартом.

Comment: @VladD: а если *внимательно* читать стандарт, то `isdigit()` не должен зависить от локали. [Can isdigit legitimately be locale dependent in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2898228)

Comment: @jfs: Не нашёл ссылок на стандарт в принятом ответе, лишь сарказм вместо обоснования. Параллельный ответ приводит ту же цитату, что и я (хотя и указывает неверный номер раздела).

---
Хотя, согласен, нашёл сноску 196. И правда.

Answer (score 2):

В с++ стандартных средств нету для таких целей. Следует либо найти библиотеку, либо написать самостоятельно дынный функционал. Логика такова: считывается строка, делится на токены по whitespace, проверяется каждый токен, если он состоит только из цифр, то это число. В вашем случае на токены разделение будет хитрее из-за скобочных последовательностей.

**Обновление**

В вашем случае удобно читать на лету, то есть:

```
char c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') //....
}
```

а преобразование символа-цифры в число:

```
int number = (c - '0');
```

[[@doomsday](/users/24309/doomsday)](/users/24309/doomsday), и у вас логическая ошибка.
Нужно так:

```
if ((chr!='(') && (chr!=')' && (chr!=' ')))
```

Comment: А если для одного символа char? Не очень понимаю, как реализовать то, что Вы сказали.

Comment: Если для одного, то все гораздо проще - просто проходите по строке, и если это цифра, то переводите её в int и записываете в какой-нибудь массив, например.

Comment: Дело в том, что заранее я не знаю, цифра это или нет.

Comment: Ну, проверить, цифра это или нет, обычно сводится к одной строчке вида:

    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') //тогда это цифра

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @iksuy, можете поправить мой код, чтобы он число целиком воспринимал, а пробел и скобки не воспринимал.